# how to use foreach loop in generating the result of mysql_query

Tags: php

Im always using while loop in generating all record in my database, and some of my friend told me that it is better to use foreach in generating record from a database, but i dont know how.

```
<?php
    $query =  mysql_query("select * from sampleTABLE");
    while($i =  mysql_fetch_array){
    echo $i['samplefieldName'];
    }
?>
```

My question is, how to display records from my database using foreach? and can some one compare it in the while loop in terms in syntax and generating its result, thank you.

Comment: "and some of my friend told me that it is better to use foreach in generating record from a database" --- don't listen that guy anymore, he doesn't understand what he is talking about.

Comment: PS: when someone gives you some advice - don't believe blindly but ask some reference/proof

Comment: sorry im noob im just Curious what other suggest... ;(

Comment: I guess the real lessons coming out of this question are: (1) Don't use `mysql_query()`; switch to a better API for your DB access and (2) Yes you can use `foreach` for recordsets if you're using one of those better APIs, but it's not any "better" than `while`; it's just a different way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use foreach instead of while here as @Zerkms says

```
 while($i =  mysql_fetch_array( $query)){
```

however ou can do this by below code but i am sure its not good approach

```
$result_list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   result_list[] = $row;
}

foreach($result_list as $item) {
   //you can now echo $item ; or whatever you want
}
```

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: im asking about foreach loop ;-( how it can be use in generating record from a database

Comment: @Robert John Concepcion: what you're asking makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. They are not recommended for use. There are two alternatives in PHP that are recommended instead -- `mysqli()` and `PDO`.

The older `mysql_xxx()` functions do **not** allow you to use `foreach` to loop through a recordset.

However, both the newer alternative APIs **do** allow this, as they implement the `Iterator` interface.

So yes, it is possible to use `foreach` to loop through a recordset in PHP, but not with the old `mysql_xxx()` functions.

You could write code like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli(....);
foreach ( $conn->query('SELECT ....') as $row ) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

or like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:....', $user, $pass);
foreach ($db->query('SELECT ....') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Having said that, please note that it's only been possible to do this with `mysqli` since PHP v5.4, so you'll need to be up-to-date with your PHP version for that. `PDO` on the other hand has supported this feature for ages.

They can, of course, both also use a `while` loop as well, and this is where your friend isn't quite right, because really there isn't any difference between `while` and `foreach` here. Switching from `while` to `foreach` won't make any difference to the performance of your code. They do the same thing under the hood. `foreach` in this case is really just "syntactic sugar".

I would strongly recommend switching to one of these newer APIs, even if you don't plan to use `foreach` to do your looping, because as I say, the old `mysql` functions are deprecated, which means that they are likely to be removed entirely from future PHP versions. So if you want your code to keep running into the future, you should switch now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to iterate over a result set using `foreach`.

`foreach` only works for cases when you already have the data fetched.

So your friend was just wrong and his advice doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `foreach` works with Iterators. `mysqli` and `PDO` recordsets are Iterators. So although his friend is wrong if he's talking specifically about `mysql_query()`, he is right in a more general sense in that it **is** possible to use `foreach` with a DB recordset.

Comment: @SDC: "he is right" "friend told me that it is better to use foreach" --- in what universe `foreach` is **better** than `while`? How would you *compare* them?

Comment: Re-read my sentence: "he is right in a more general sense in that it is possible". I wasn't saying anything about it being better or not, but I was saying that you're incorrect in saying it's not possible at all. As we both know, there's no real difference here logically between `while` and `foreach`. Using `foreach` in this case is pure syntactic sugar.

Comment: @SDC: there is a huge difference. You cannot use foreach with things that are not iterable. " you're incorrect in saying it's not possible at all." ---- prove your words. Show how you would iterate over `mysql_query` result with `foreach`

Comment: @SDC: "but I was saying that you're incorrect in saying it's not possible at all" --- am I still incorrect? The question is about `mysql_query`, I answered to the question about `mysql_query`, I didn't say anything about other DBALs. Thoughts? "uh, I clearly said that mysql_query couldn't use foreach." --- you clearly said I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@zerkms

I also thought like that.. But following works...

My 'tbl_login' table structure also attached as a

```
<?php
    include '../common/dbConnection.php';

     class foreachtest{
        function foreachtesting(){
            $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_login";
            $query_result=$GLOBALS['con']->query($sql);
            return $query_result;
        }
    }

    $myobject = new foreachtest();
    $result=$myobject->foreachtesting();


    foreach ($result as $a){
        echo $a['username'];
    }

?>
```

[tbl_login MYSQL table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOldy.png)